# Facing Pipeline Busy issue while loading data in Greenplum using data stage

Tags: greenplum

We are getting errors while loading data(large volume) in Greenplum through data stage jobs.

There are multiple jobs running sequentially. there is no particular job that fails. it is randomly. if on the 1st day Job1 fails, on the 2nd day Job2 gets fail.

We have also observed that it only impact the jobs that have to load a high volume of data.

Please find the error, we have got so fer.

day 1----------
Message:
STG_DEPS_G,0: The following SQL statement failed: INSERT INTO GPCC_ET_20211114015751397_14836_2 SELECT DEPT, DEPT_NAME, BUYER, MERCH, PROFIT_CALC_TYPE, PURCHASE_TYPE, GROUP_NO, BUD_INT, BUD_MKUP, TOTAL_MARKET_AMT, MARKUP_CALC_TYPE, OTB_CALC_TYPE, MAX_AVG_COUNTER, AVG_TOLERANCE_PCT, DEPT_VAT_INCL_IND, CREATE_ID, CREATE_DATETIME FROM staging.STG_DEPS. The statement reported the following reason: [SQLCODE=08S01][Native=373,254] [IBM (DataDirect OEM)][ODBC Greenplum Wire Protocol driver][Greenplum]ERROR: http response code 501 from gpfdist (gpfdist://DDCETLMIG:8000/DDCETLMIG_14836_gpw_11_3_20211114015751366): HTTP/1.0 501 pipe is busy, close the pipe and try again  (seg0 192.168.199.10:6000 pid=25824)(File url_curl.c; Line 474; Routine check_response; ) (CC_GPCommon::checkThreadStatusThrow, file CC_GPCommon.cpp, line 808)
The following SQL statement failed: INSERT INTO GPCC_ET_20211114015751397_14836_2 SELECT DEPT, DEPT_NAME, BUYER, MERCH, PROFIT_CALC_TYPE, PURCHASE_TYPE, GROUP_NO, BUD_INT, BUD_MKUP, TOTAL_MARKET_AMT, MARKUP_CALC_TYPE, OTB_CALC_TYPE, MAX_AVG_COUNTER, AVG_TOLERANCE_PCT, DEPT_VAT_INCL_IND, CREATE_ID, CREATE_DATETIME FROM staging.STG_DEPS. The statement reported the following reason: [SQLCODE=08S01][Native=373,254] [IBM (DataDirect OEM)][ODBC Greenplum Wire Protocol driver][Greenplum]ERROR: http response code 501 from gpfdist (gpfdist://DDCETLMIG:8000/DDCETLMIG_14836_gpw_11_3_20211114015751366): HTTP/1.0 501 pipe is busy, close the pipe and try again  (seg0 192.168.199.10:6000 pid=25824)(File url_curl.c; Line 474; Routine check_response; ) (CC_GPCommon::checkThreadStatusThrow, file CC_GPCommon.cpp, line 808)

---

### day 2

### STG_RPM_ZONE,0: The following SQL statement failed: INSERT INTO GPCC_ET_20211114093430218_8212_0 SELECT ZONE_ID, ZONE_DISPLAY_ID, ZONE_GROUP_ID, NAME, CURRENCY_CODE, BASE_IND, LOCK_VERSION FROM STAGING.STG_RPM_ZONE. The statement reported the following reason: [SQLCODE=08S01][Native=373,254] [IBM (DataDirect OEM)][ODBC Greenplum Wire Protocol driver][Greenplum]ERROR: http response code 501 from gpfdist (gpfdist://DDCETLMIG:8004/DDCETLMIG_8212_gpw_0_0_20211114093430186): HTTP/1.0 501 pipe is busy, close the pipe and try again  (seg1 192.168.199.11:6000 pid=26726)(File url_curl.c; Line 474; Routine check_response; ) (CC_GPCommon::checkThreadStatusThrow, file CC_GPCommon.cpp, line 808)
The following SQL statement failed: INSERT INTO GPCC_ET_20211114093430218_8212_0 SELECT ZONE_ID, ZONE_DISPLAY_ID, ZONE_GROUP_ID, NAME, CURRENCY_CODE, BASE_IND, LOCK_VERSION FROM STAGING.STG_RPM_ZONE. The statement reported the following reason: [SQLCODE=08S01][Native=373,254] [IBM (DataDirect OEM)][ODBC Greenplum Wire Protocol driver][Greenplum]ERROR: http response code 501 from gpfdist (gpfdist://DDCETLMIG:8004/DDCETLMIG_8212_gpw_0_0_20211114093430186): HTTP/1.0 501 pipe is busy, close the pipe and try again  (seg1 192.168.199.11:6000 pid=26726)(File url_curl.c; Line 474; Routine check_response; ) (CC_GPCommon::checkThreadStatusThrow, file CC_GPCommon.cpp, line 808)

### day 3

### Event type:Fatal
Timestamp:11/15/2021 9:27:36 AM
Message:
SUB_CLASS,3: APT_PMMessagePort::dispatch:ERROR: header = 04F02E20SUBPROC_SUPPORT_EOW, savedDispatchPosition = 04F02E20, currentDispatchPosition_ = 04F02E1FS, currentInputPosition_ = 04F02E58, buffer_ = 04F02E20, this = 04EEA1E0

### Day 4

Message:
STG_GROUPS_G,0: The following SQL statement failed: INSERT INTO GPCC_ET_20211115015013039_2400_0 SELECT GROUP_NO, GROUP_NAME, BUYER, MERCH, DIVISION, CREATE_ID, CREATE_DATETIME FROM staging.STG_GROUPS. The statement reported the following reason: [SQLCODE=08S01][Native=373,254] [IBM (DataDirect OEM)][ODBC Greenplum Wire Protocol driver][Greenplum]ERROR: http response code 501 from gpfdist (gpfdist://DDCETLMIG:8009/DDCETLMIG_2400_gpw_1_1_20211115015013023): HTTP/1.0 501 pipe is busy, close the pipe and try again  (seg5 192.168.199.12:6001 pid=1167)(File url_curl.c; Line 474; Routine check_response; ) (CC_GPCommon::checkThreadStatusThrow, file CC_GPCommon.cpp, line 808)
The following SQL statement failed: INSERT INTO GPCC_ET_20211115015013039_2400_0 SELECT GROUP_NO, GROUP_NAME, BUYER, MERCH, DIVISION, CREATE_ID, CREATE_DATETIME FROM staging.STG_GROUPS. The statement reported the following reason: [SQLCODE=08S01][Native=373,254] [IBM (DataDirect OEM)][ODBC Greenplum Wire Protocol driver][Greenplum]ERROR: http response code 501 from gpfdist (gpfdist://DDCETLMIG:8009/DDCETLMIG_2400_gpw_1_1_20211115015013023): HTTP/1.0 501 pipe is busy, close the pipe and try again  (seg5 192.168.199.12:6001 pid=1167)(File url_curl.c; Line 474; Routine check_response; ) (CC_GPCommon::checkThreadStatusThrow, file CC_GPCommon.cpp, line 808)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score -1):

A couple of questions:

You indicated there are multiple jobs running sequentially?   Does that mean there are multiple concurrent jobs each running a set of sequential jobs?  Or is there one job running multiple sequential steps?   If it is the first, I would check to make sure no jobs are using the same gpfdist ports.

Is DataStage connecting through a proxy server?  That could potentially be causing a problem (common cause of 501 errors according to google lookup).

Finally, what is the throughput speed of the NIC or NICs being used to connect DataStage/gpfdist to Greenplum?   Also, what is the interconnect speed between each segment/segment host in Greenplum?   If either of these is less than 10gig, your network may not be able to support really high throughput.